# How to filter a JSON object based on a condition and then just select few keys from the filtered object using the JQ parser

Tags: json, jq

I am having a below JSON structure,which has an array of objects.

```
 {
  "payload": {
    "location": {
      "uid": 1,
      "type": "foo"
    },
    "name": "foo",
    "maxResults": 10
  },
  "product": {
    "uid": "1232323",
    "source": "foo",
    "service": "pricing",
    "version": "0.1",
    "time": 1507602150899,
    "type": "mobile",
    "id": 1
  }
}
{
  "payload": {
    "location": {
      "uid": 2,
      "type": "bar"
    },
    "name": "bar",
    "maxResults": 10
  },
  "product": {
    "uid": "244434242",
    "source": "bar",
    "service": "pricing",
    "version": "0.2",
    "time": "1507602ds0899",
    "type": "phone",
    "id": 2
  }
}
```

I want to filter the object based on condition, where `product.type == mobile` and then in matching objects, I just want to the `id` and `service` fields. So in above example, below would be the O/P.

```
{
  "service" : "pricing",
  "id" : 1
}
```

I am able to extract the matching objects using the

```
cat myjson.json | jq 'select(.product.type == "moble")'
```

but after that how can I filter only the `service` and `id` field of object ?

Comment: Your `JSON` input is syntactically not correct, Copy paste it in https://jsonlint.com/ and see it for yourself

Comment: @Inian , thats fine as i said , using the `cat myjson.json | jq 'select(.product.type == "moble")'` , I am able to get the object matching my criteria., JQ works fine for it.

Comment: You have a typo in `moble` and unless the json is fixed, `jq` can't parse it

Comment: @Inian , yeah thats a typo, but then why in first place I am getting the O/P?

Comment: @Inian , Thanks I am just updating my JSON. please check back in few seconds and advise how can I get just few values from the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this would help you:

```
map(select(.product.type == "mobile")) | .[] | {id: .product.id, service: .product.service}
```

https://jqplay.org/s/6zMyKjTehN

Comment: I want to use the `jq` parser .

Answer (score 0):

The data as currently shown in the question is not strictly JSON, but since the OP mentions the input is supposed to be an array, the following assumes the data is a JSON array of the objects.

A succinct solution is then:

```
data[] | .product | select(.type == "mobile") | {service, id}
```

With the input data adjusted as described above, the output would be as shown, namely:

```
{"service":"pricing","id":1}
```